# Deleting a list of keys

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

In Javascript, I have an object and I wish to delete multiple keys:

```
x = {"id":2,"user_id":1,"name":"document_name","description":"the  document","file_type":null,"file_id":null}
delete x.file_type
delete x.file_id
```

Results in:

```
Object {id: 2, user_id: 1, name: "document_name", description: "the document"}
```

I would prefer to delete all keys in a single command, maybe passing an array of keys?
Alternatively, use some type of underscore/lodash filter to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Underscore you can use [`_.omit`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) to exclude unnecessary keys:

```
_.omit(x, 'file_type', 'file_id');
```

Note however, that `omit` returns a *copy* of the object. So it's not the same as using `delete` operator.

Check the demo below.

```js
var x = {"id":2,"user_id":1,"name":"document_name","description":"the  document","file_type":null,"file_id":null};
var result = _.omit(x, 'file_type', 'file_id');

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
['file_type', 'file_id'].forEach(function (key) {
  delete x[key];  
});
```

Demo: [http://jsbin.com/vevotu/1/](http://jsbin.com/vevotu/1/edit?js,console)